# Google Analytics for Android failing to send any data

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

From Application onCreate(), to test event/screen logging:

```
public static void logUserAction(String eventName) {
        Timber.i("Logging to Google Analytics");
        Tracker t = getTracker();
        t.setScreenName(eventName);
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
        t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                .setCategory("Event")
                .setAction(eventName)
                .setLabel(eventName)
                .setValue(1)
                .build());
}

synchronized static Tracker getTracker() {
    if (googleAnalyticsTracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(application);
        googleAnalyticsTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return googleAnalyticsTracker;
}
```

Config file, global_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-ACTUAL_VALUE_USED_HERE</string>
</resources>
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

...

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Build file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.0.0'
```

The UA tracking code I'm using is definitely correct. The project builds and executes, however although the log message is shown to confirm the code is called, absolutely nothing happens in debug or release builds. No data is showing in Analytics, and there is nothing in Logcat to guide me.

What did I miss?

Comment: Did you just create your Google Analytics ID? Because it can take time to show the first results

Comment: You're right - feel free to add an answer and I'll accept & upvote, it might save someone else the pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like my comment said, you have to wait some times after the "Google Analytics ID" creation, before you can view any reports.